# Open ball not contained in a hyperplane

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to prove that for the set of infinite dimensional vectors

$\vec{v_j}=(v_1,...v_j=0,...)$

can not include an open sphere.

This is easy to grasp geometrically, as {$\vec{v_j}$} defines a hyperplane, therefore no open ball can be contained by a lower dimensional space. Now I want to make a concrete mathematical argument about that. I thought of using the definition of an open ball around $\vec{v_j}$ of radius r. The that implies that any element in the open ball x satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x^i-v^i_j|<r$. Now I define a new vector $\vec{y}=(v_1,...v_j=r/2,...)$. Thus, y is identical to $\vec{v_j}$ except for the j$^{th}$ element. Nonetheless, y always falls in the open sphere no matter the value of r, yet it is outside the span of the $\vec{v_j}$. Therefore, the hyperplane as defined above can not contain an open sphere.

Is my proof correct and mathematically rigorous. How I could write it down better knowing that the vectors are sequences $(v_i)_{i\epsilon N}$ and the metric is the standard norm on $\ell_p$ Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Are you sure? Is there any way to make it more rigorous. Excuse me for insisting but my Prof. insists all the time about being mathematically rigorous etc, and not having a background in maths, I want to be sure and precise. Thank you in any case

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am in an $\ell_p$ space. Thank you

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I modified the announcement. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is a normed vector space under a norm $\|\cdot\|$ and $0 \neq v \in U$, then no open ball $O_\varepsilon$ (where $O_\varepsilon = \{ u \mid \|u\| < \varepsilon\}$ with $\varepsilon > 0$) can be contained in the hyperplane $H$ defined by the equation $v = 0$ w.r.t. any basis of $U$ containing $v$. To see this, note that if $O_\varepsilon \subseteq H$, then so is $O_1$. But, if $V = \{tv \mid t \in \Bbb{R}\}$ is the one-dimensional subspace of $U$ spanned by $v$, then $O_1 \cap V$ is the open unit ball of $V$ under the norm given by the restriction of $\|\cdot\|$ to $V$, and that cannot comprise a single point.

Comment: @ArthanRob what is O1 exactly?

Comment: @GeordieD: thanks. I've included the definition.

Comment: @ArthanRob . And the fact that it cannot comprise a single point, is a contradiction to the definition of the open sphere...

Comment: That's right. In any normed vector space $\|u\|$ is the supremum of the set of $t \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $t > 0$ and $u/t \in O_1$ and that would not be defined if there were no such $t$.